# Cannot find gazebo_ros plugins after update from 1.9.4 to 1.9.5

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just updated gazebo-prerelease through ubuntu(12.04) update manager from 1.9.4 to 1.9.5 and now gazebo cannot find the gasebo_ros plugins which were working well till now.

---

Error [Plugin.hh:127] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so: libsdf.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error [Plugin.hh:127] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so: libsdf.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

---

These were the only plugins I was using for you. I did a search for the plugins and found them in the ros simulator_gazebo stack for some reason. Adding them, to GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH doesnt solve the issue either.

ROS: Groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3920/cannot-find-gazebo_ros-plugins-after-update-from-1.9.4-to-1.9.5/) by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try using the main gazebo debian (which is currently 1.9.0). This should work with `gazebo_ros`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-26**:
Works! with main debian. Had to install the gazebo_ros_pkgs from source once more to make it run. Thank you

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-29**:
Hi,

I quess It all runs with the source install again if you update and rebuild `gazebo_ros_pkgs` too.
libsdf.so has been replaced with libsdformat.so in the newest releases.